# Generate a dynamic table in a <td>

Tags: javascript, html-table

```
function td(id)
{
    var td=document.getElementById(id+'');
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var tbody=document.createElement('tbody');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var tdchild = document.createElement('td');
    tdchild.innerHTML="<input type=text name=txt size=2>";
    tr.appendChild(tdchild);
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    td.appendChild(table);
}
```

I want to generate a table in side a td on click of a button. Its not happening this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct to me, and it seems to work as expected.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMjBt/).

Are you sure you are calling the td function with the right ID, and that the ID is in the td element, and not in the table element?

Comment: Edited with a click event example, perhaps your problem is in the click event listener.

Answer (score 0):

That works for me.  Do you have a click listener defined that will run this function?  Does a td exist with the specified id?